# Find and Resolve Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' Error

Tags: c#

Where am I getting this error and how does one resolve it?

```
namespace SimpleInterest
{
    class Programsi
    {
        static void Main(string[]args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter your age: ");
            int age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Deposit amount(P)      Age   Time      Amount(SI) \n");
            for(int y = 1; y <= 5; y++)
            {
                if(age>=60)
                {
                    int SI = (23000*y*7)/100;
                    Console.WriteLine("23000.00   {0}   {1}   {2}",age, y, SI);
                }
                else
                {
                    int SI = (23000*y*6)/100;
                    Console.WriteLine("23000.00   {0}   {1}   {2}",age, y, SI);
                }
           
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably this line: `int age = Console.ReadLine();`, will return a string object, if you think it's an `int`, you'll need to explicitly convert it.

Comment: Console.Readline() returns a string - do a conversion like Convert.ToInt32()

Comment: `int age = Console.ReadLine();` <-- here's your problem, You'll need to parse the result of ReadLine` to determine if it contains a numerci value and then convert it to a number.

Comment: you need to parse your string into n int. `int age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` Put it inside a `try` to capture parsing exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You are using int age = Console.ReadLine(); try to int as this ReadLine will read the complete line as string.

You can try below
int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`. You need to manually convert it to an `int`. Here's an approach to do it safely:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter your age: ");

string input = Console.ReadLine(); // Change that to a string
if (!int.TryParse(input, out var age)) // Try to convert the input to an int
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Deposit amount(P)      Age   Time      Amount(SI) \n");
for(int y = 1; y <= 5; y++)
{
    if(age>=60)
    {
        int SI = (23000*y*7)/100;
        Console.WriteLine("23000.00   {0}   {1}   {2}",age, y, SI);
    }
    else
    {
        int SI = (23000*y*6)/100;
        Console.WriteLine("23000.00   {0}   {1}   {2}",age, y, SI);
    }         
}
```